# Mobile Phone Browser Emulators/Simulators

Tags: android, mobile-phone, emulator

I work in QA in a .NET shop and recently part of my testing process has started to involve testing our company website on mobile devices.  At least one of our techs uses an HTC Desire.

After tons of googling I still can't find a good online emulator for testing websites on different types of mobile devices.  Is anyone aware of a website that I can test across multiple mobile platforms? Or even an online HTC or Blackberry browser emulator?

I've found an iphone/opera mini simulator, but that's about it. 
Also, I realize there are a lot of SDK's that include emulators, but I'd rather not have to set up an entire SDK just to use an emulator.

---

I did find this link http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Mobile_browser_testing that seems to be a good start.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464089/simulators-emulators-for-mobile-browser-testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our company has used [DeviceAnywhere Studio](http://www.deviceanywhere.com/) for testing.  It is a great way for us to get a hold of a variety of phones we don't have on hand for QA.  It's a commercial service, so not free, but it does a great job of letting you remotely interact with just about any mobile device on the market.

Answer (score 1):

It's pain.  I know of no such online services (which isn't to say they don't exist).

However the standalone Windows Mobile Emulator is available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=a6f6adaf-12e3-4b2f-a394-356e2c2fb114&displaylang=en)

Comment: Thanks!  I will download that one.  Hopefully Android will put a standalone emulator out in the near future as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [website run by Samsung](http://developer.samsung.com/remoteTestLab.do) that permits you to see how your app will run on Samsung smartphones. You could run an hello world, and then exit and run the browser ;-)

Comment: Could you provide a link, please?

Comment: http://developer.samsung.com/remoteTestLab.do

Answer (score 1):

Blackberry simulators are available [here](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/resources/simulators.jsp) and exist for most current models. It's not an online tool, but at least it is not a full SDK.