# Emulator that can view website's mobile version

Tags: windows-7, web-development, mobile-phone, ide, emulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mobile Phone Browser Emulators/Simulators](https://superuser.com/questions/138772/mobile-phone-browser-emulators-simulators)

Does anyone knows programs that can view websites in their mobile version?
I mean an emulator or something? I'm using windows 7.

I know one software called [MobiOne](http://www.genuitec.com/mobile/features/). But this isn't freeware.
I am just starting as a web developer and getting small clients. I want to find a free tool to support my career for now.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is more than you asked for but you could install BlueStacks - the Android emulator. Free and simple.

That way you could use different browsers too.

Answer (score 0):

If it suits your needs, you can use this java applet to emulate Opera Mini Browser mobile version.

http://www.opera.com/developer/tools/mini/

Hope it helps